# Change systray icon colors

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I would like to change the colors of icons in system tray (or to be presize, set them to dark theme  - to use white icons).

In my app, I have specific color scheme given to me and I'm using it. I have the background color of system tray (the place where your battery, signal strength, wifi strength etc...) shows up set to specific color and when I'm in using dark theme, it works fine.

But when I change the phone to light theme, I'd like to use white icons, since my system tray is set to dark background (to feel monolithic with the application), but the icons in the systray are still dark no matter which collor I set it to have.

I'm setting it up in XAML, here's the code:

```
...
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True"
shell:SystemTray.BackgroundColor="#FF222222"
shell:SystemTray.ForegroundColor="#FFFFFFFF">
```

What Am I doing wrong. Is it even possible to change the foreground color theme?

Comment: Remove the opacity like => #222222

Answer (score 1):

I think you Might referencing wrong assembly. this may help you by using `Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone`

you can simply use this in XAML code

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
...
xmlns:phoneshell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
phoneshell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True"
phoneshell:SystemTray.BackgroundColor="Blue">
```

Comment: nope, the assembly I'm referencing is `xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"`. An my problem isn't with background, setting background works, it's setting foreground that doesn't respond.

Comment: @mishan: have you tried simple colors like `'Black'` instated `#-----`

Comment: yup, not working. But as I'm thinking about it it might be that I'm testinng it in simulator. It might be working on an actual phone. I'm gonna need to wait a bit before the phone is back from testers and test again.

Answer (score 1):

From code you can try:

```
SystemTray.ForegroundColor = new System.Windows.Media.Color() { R = _r, G = _g, B = _b };
```